# Using GROUP BY on SQL to get a summary of my transactions table (buy and sell)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, group-by

So I have the following table:

select * from transactions

```
id  symbol  name          shares    price   status  time                 user_id
1   NFLX    Netflix, Inc.   10      371       1     2020-03-24 13:31:17    3
2   AAPL    Apple, Inc.     2       236.24    1     2020-03-24 13:31:43    3
3   NFLX    Netflix, Inc.   2       369.28    2     2020-03-24 13:32:01    3
```

I'm trying to get a result like this using a select to display for the user:

```
id  symbol  name          shares    price   status  time                 user_id
1   NFLX    Netflix, Inc.  **8**    371       1     2020-03-24 13:31:17    3
2   AAPL    Apple, Inc.     2       236.24    1     2020-03-24 13:31:43    3
```

The shares for NFLX are now 8 (10 shares with status=1 (buy) and 2 shares with status=2 (sell), so 10-2=8). I've tried using GROUP BY symbol, but the results I got didn't group the quantity of shares, they only left the NFLX with 10 shares.

Here is the sentence I used:
select symbol, shares, status from transactions group by symbol, shares

```
symbol  shares  status
AAPL      2       1
NFLX      2       2
NFLX     10       1
```

I'm away from SQL for some years now and I got really rusty, this is so simple and I can't get through it. I'm sad :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation for `shares`:

```
select symbol,
       sum(case when status = 1 then shares else - shares end) as net_shares
from t
group by symbol;
```

It is not clear where the other columns are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    id,
    symbol,
    name,
    sum(case when status = 1 then shares else -shares end) shares
    user_id
from mytable t
group by id, symbol, name, user_id
```